# Groovy - как получить случайное число и округлить его до целого значения

Tags: groovy

Мне нужно что то вроде `J = round(random(n))`

Answer (score 1):

Получить произвольное значение, умножить до желаемого целого и округлить.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
```